# what jquery modal window can work well in ie quirks mode?

Tags: jquery, css, modal-window

Our project's template html has a quirks declaration,which is `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`, unfortunately this can't be easily allowed to modify. I tried colobox 1.3.19 and discovered it's css work badly. So is there any other jquery based modal window library solution with a good look and feel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: Hi Salil: it can open modal window on ie8 quirks mode, but the only defect is the footer part is smaller than the width of upper image frame, and its document is very insufficient, I want to include the content html of a iframe, because the source's jquery event handling functions don't work when I use colorbox to include html directly,is lightbox for showing images? I need to display some plain htmls in a modal window.

Comment: Yes it can show image, text, etc... you can even use AJAX with it.... can you show me your problem at jsfiddle ?

Comment: please find the image at i49.tinypic.com/ou2qdk.jpg ,and how to put content html of iframe into lightbox modal window?

Comment: finally I found prettyPhotot a relative good plugin for quirks mode, actually it's 2nd version of lightbox.